# Smart Chain contract Boucing

Tags: coinbase.com, fraud, smartcontracts

I am a beginner in crypto, and I have recently invested on a platform. At the withdrawal time, I got paid via CoinBase Wallet(CW) in USDT. I could see the money in CW. Trying to withdraw, I understand that there was a contract behind, as CW was telling me: you do not have enough BNB to make this transaction.

So after few weeks I followed company procedure and sent them enough BNBs, the company told me that a contract has been initiated on CW so I expect to receive a pop up in 48h and I will be able to accept the contract, in other terms being signed in the network, like a time tax fee.

But they finally told me that the sign in process keeps bouncing out since I took time to provide the BNBs and they will paid me directly to my bank account. They ask me for my bank credentials for their api process, but I refused.

I guess I should not give them any cards, or bank interface details, isn't it ?

Do you think I have any chance to get my withdrawal or I have been simply scammed ?

Sorry if my message is not properly indicated.